# Display Windows Touch Keyboard

Tags: qt, windows-8, touch, qml, multitouch-keyboard

i am writing an application for windows 8 with Qt and Qml. I want a touch keyboard appears when I set focus to a text input field, such as a search box. Things like textInput.openSoftwareInputPanel(); doesn’t work for a desktop application. Windows 8 have a default touch keyboard, it is possible to display this keyboard. I can’t find any solution for this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which Qt version do you use?

Comment: i am using Qt 5.1. At the moment i try to run the osk keyboard with a QProzess like: QProcess* myProcess = new QProcess(this);
  QStringList arguments;
  
  myProcess->start("osk",arguments); but this don't work with osk, with calc for example it works. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i have solved the problem, with:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
    QString program = "explorer.exe";
    QString folder = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe";
    process->start(program, QStringList() << folder);
```

i can call the osk keyboard in an external process. With a signal/ slot to my textInput field i call a function who start this process.

Thank you for help.

Comment: ...and that causes the entered text to appear in the textinput??

Comment: in the onClicked method a set the textfield.focus = true;
                            textfield.forceActiveFocus(); and than the text appears in the textInput field.

Comment: For Window 10, use `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Ink\TabTip.exe` :)