# Nonexclusive Borderless Fullscreen with QML

Tags: qt, qml

I need a fullscreen window in QML. However, it must not be exclusive fullscreen. My application must work with accessible applications such as Windows On-screen Keyboard and Magnifier. If my application runs in exclusive fullscreen, it will stay on top of other accessible applications making them useless.

With QWidget, I can call showFullscreen() and get what I needed (a window that cover the entire screen while letting other accessible applications stay on top of it.

With QML, there are a few few ways to make the window fullscreen. However, all of the methods I've tried result in exclusive fullscreen.

I've tried [all answers suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014298/full-screen-desktop-application-with-qml). To summarize I've tried setting visibility: "FullScreen". I've tried manually setting the width and height to match the screen resolution.

Comment: Did you try to set `flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint`, `Qt.FramelessWindowHint` or `visibility: Qt.WindowFullScreen` for the window?

Comment: @folibis Yes, I have tried flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint, Qt.FramelessWindowHint while while setting the width and height to match the screen resolution. The problem is as soon as I set the width and height to match the screen resolutions, the window goes into exclusive fullscreen. Also tried visibility: Qt.WindowFullScreen.

Comment: @snotboogie  Hi, Did you find a solution to your problem? I am facing the same one. I can display the keyboard osk.exe in non fullscreen app, even maximized, and keep the focus on the TextEdit element, but when I use fullscreen app, the keyboark stays behind my window.

Comment: @SteveTJS No, I still don't have a solution. I just use QWidgets instead of QML

Comment: OK, too bad :).

Comment: See my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41145005/qt-fullscreen-window-hiding-win8-10-touch-keyboard/58621175#58621175